# Leaving `unique_ptr` unset until I am ready to allocate it: Is this how I re-assign it?

Tags: c++, c++11

This example is in the context of iOS, but the principle applies elsewhere...

```
// global variable... 
std::unique_ptr<Foo> global_foo_handle; 

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // use Obj-C to compute a valid path string
    const char * path = [[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithUTF8String: "file.txt"]] UTF8String];
    // Only now can I call the ctor of my foo. 
    global_foo_handle = std::move(std::unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(path)));
}
```

This doesn't *really* look all that sane to me. Is there no cleaner way? I see that the only valid unique_ptr `operator =` are move assignments. I suppose it's clear enough what's being done here. It also seems like I can omit the `std::move` so long as the ephemeral `unique_ptr` made for the newly allocated Foo remains a temporary rather than being made into an lvalue.

I guess I'm sort of wondering why there isn't an operator= that takes a pointer to `T`? That way we skip the creation of the temporary unique_ptr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use reset method to achieve this - See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/reset/

Comment: cppreference.com is generally more accurate.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset

Comment: @BenVoigt  - Perhaps you are right - Perhaps not - I just find the reference given is more navigable.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need the `std::move`...

```
global_foo_handle = std::unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(path));
```

Or you can just reset the value...

```
global_foo_handle.reset(new Foo(path));
```

However, you must understand that the deleter is part of the unique_ptr type, and any pointer assigned to the unique_ptr via `reset` will be deleted by the deleter of the original unique_ptr object.

Comment: `reset()`. that's what I want I think.